# How can I pin an NSPopover to a selected NSTableCellView in swift5

Tags: nstableview, swift5, nspopover, nstablecellview

I have the code shown below, that pins an NSPopover to my NSTableView. I've looked all over Google, and SO, but I cannot find a way to pin the popover to a specific (selected) cell.

@objc func tableViewDoubleAction(sender: NSTableCellView) {

```
let message = "Please Choose"
let controller = NSViewController()
controller.view = NSView(frame: CGRect(x: CGFloat(100), y: CGFloat(50), width: CGFloat(300), height: CGFloat(250)))

let popover = NSPopover()
popover.contentViewController = controller
popover.contentSize = controller.view.frame.size

popover.behavior = .transient
popover.animates = true


popover.show(relativeTo: sender.bounds, of: sender as NSView, preferredEdge: NSRectEdge.maxY)
```

Here's an image to demonstrate the issue:

[image: an image]

Comment: Is `sender` the `NSTableCellView`?

Comment: Right now, it's the tableview itself. I haven't figured out how to pass the actual cell.

Comment: Pass the cell view instead of `sender`?

Comment: I've updated the question after changing the source view to an NSTableCellView. I still get the same result. The popover doesn't align with the selected cell. I'm missing something.

Comment: Changing the class of `sender` doesn't make `NSTableVIew` change the passed value, it's still the table view. Get the clicked row, get the rect of the row and use this rect. Or use the cell view or the row view.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not getting this.. Would you be able to show me the code to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation of `NSTableView.doubleAction`:

> The clickedRow and clickedColumn properties allow you to determine which row and column the double-click occurred in or if, rather than in a row, the double-click occurred in a column heading.

```
@objc func tableViewDoubleAction(sender: NSTableView) {
    let row = sender.clickedRow
```

From the documentation of `clickedRow`:

> The index of the row the user clicked to trigger an action message. Returns –1 if the user clicked in an area of the table view not occupied by table rows.

```
    if row >= 0 {
```

`NSTableView` has a method `rect(ofRow:)`:

> Returns the rectangle containing the row at the specified index.

```
        let rowRect = sender.rect(ofRow: row)
```

Use this rect to position the popover

```
        popover.show(relativeTo: rowRect, of: sender, preferredEdge: NSRectEdge.maxY)
```

Put it all together:

```
@objc func tableViewDoubleAction(sender: NSTableView) {
    let row = sender.clickedRow
    if row >= 0 {
        // create the popover
        let rowRect = sender.rect(ofRow: row)
        popover.show(relativeTo: rowRect, of: sender, preferredEdge: NSRectEdge.maxY)
    }
}
```